# Xpages ckeditor and ImagePaste addon - anyone implemented this succesfully?

Tags: xpages

Is there anyone having implemented ImagePaste addon http://ckeditor.com/addon/imagepaste for CKEDITOR with Xpages? Any hints how to put both together?